# Why is Reaper not picking up signal from my MIDI controller?

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa, jack, midi

I own a M-Audio Axiom 61 MIDI controller and I'm trying to configure with Reaper 5, which now has quite a stable pure Linux version.  I am **not** using WINE at all.

I followed everything in [this](http://tedfelix.com/linux/linux-midi.html) incredibly helpful walkthrough, and was able to get all the steps to work, so I know that the setup works.

I run the following `jackd` server from the command line, connect and turn my MIDI controller on, start up Reaper and configure it with JACK to be able to see my MIDI controller in the `MIDI Devices` list, where I enable it as an input.

```
pasuspender -- jackd -d alsa --device hw:0 --rate 44100 --period 128
```

I then add a track, select all MIDI channels as the input, turn on record monitoring and arm it.

Reaper doesn't pick up any signal when I play a key from my MIDI controller, but when I fire up a Virtual MIDI it does.

Comment: Does the device show up in the output of `aseqdump -l`? Do you get any events when you run `aseqdump` on that port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this working last night.  I was using `jackd` from the command line, and didn't realize that I needed `a2jmidid` to bridge my MIDI controller.

The other option is to run `qjackctl` and under the MIDI tab connect your MIDI controller to an output.

Comment: Hi. From this answer, I can now get audio output using virtual midi keyboard in reaper & also don't see the JACK server error message that I used to see before. However, I haven't been able to successfully link my MIDI Keyboard (Nektar SE49) to the system. I can see it is detected in the ALSA control panel, but reaper doesn't find it.

I have `a2jmidid` installed. I also run `qjackctl` in a separate terminal before running repaer, but I can't follow what you said about adding the midi device to an output in reaper settings. I've enabled a midi input and output channel, but that didnt' help.

Comment: @progyammer I will have a look from home this evening, but in the settings, under MIDI controllers, you should be able to try to detect your keyboard.  If you cannot detect it, you should be able to add your keyboard manually by manufacturer and model.  I'll try to give you a little more detailed information later.

Comment: Thank you for a2jmidid, now Reaper able to find my midi device, but there is another problem. I can see that it find the device, but it looks like Reaper needs some plugin to "make a sound". How do you fix this situation?

Comment: Did you add a track and assign MIDI controller as input?